# OpenSSL and Trusted System Certifcates

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

So I already know how to specify locations for trusted certificates using `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()`. Now the documentation says the following:

> SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() specifies the locations for ctx, at
>   which CA certificates for verification purposes are located. The
>   certificates available via CAfile and CApath are trusted.

And also says:

> When looking up CA certificates, the OpenSSL library will first search
>   the certificates in CAfile, then those in CApath.

That's fine. But nothing is mentioned about the trusted system certificates residing in the **OPENSSLDIR**.

1. Are system certificates checked after both CAfile and CApath fail?
2. Does a call to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths()` override `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()`? Or do they work side by side, i.e., both trusted system certificates and the ones specified by CAfile and CApath?
3. If the certificates are manually added to the certificate store using `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store()`, i.e., `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` is not called at all, what happens in that case? Are only the store certificates checked? Anyway to disable/enable checking trusted system certificates in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright .. So I took a stab at it and found out what I needed to know.
**Setup:**
 - Simple client and server with peer verification enabled on both sides
 - I created two CAs. Let's call them SS (self-signed) and TR (trusted).
 - SS was used to create a client (SS_C) and server (SS_S) certificates.
 - TR was used to create a client (TR_C) and server (TR_S) certificates.
 - The TR CA was hashed and added to the default CA directory.

**Foolproof Test:**
 - `openssl verify` of SS_C and SS_S fail unless I specify the `CAfile`
 - `openssl verify` of TR_C and TR_S succeed
*Result as expected*

**Client/Server Basic Test:**
 - No verification paths calls: SS fails -- TR fails
 - Call to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths`: SS fails -- TR succeeds
 - Call to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` with SS as CAfile: SS succeeds  -- TR fails
*Result as expected*

---

Now, let's get to the more interesting stuff.
**Calls to both `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths` and `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`:**
In this case, calls to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` were always made with SS as the CAfile.
 - TR succeeds -- irrespective of the order of the calls
 - SS succeeds -- irrespective of the order of the calls
*Interesting result -- at least to me*
*Now, I can expect that using the certificate store will work as well*

**Using the `X509_STORE` instead of `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`:**
In this case, I created a byte array of the SS CA, got the context's certificate store, and added the SS CA to it.
 - Only get context's store and add SS CA to it: SS succeeds -- TR fails
 - Only get context's store (to test whether it adds the default trusted certificates): SS fails -- TR fails
 - Call to `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths` + get context's store and add SS CA to it: SS succeeds -- TR succeeds
*Great .. it indeed works*